# Is there a way to merge two DataTables and only preserve changes for specific columns?

Tags: c#, winforms, merge, datatable

I have the following two tables, which are imported from Excel files into my Windows Forms app. These files are created automatically and it is not possible to change them, unfortunately. I simplified all examples below. Actually the tables have more than 40 columns and over 100k rows each.

The first table includes customer billing information, where customer is the customer number, which I use as primary key.

```
BillingTable

Customer(PK)      Name        Address      Type
------------  -------------  ----------  -----------
1               Customer 1    Address 1    Billing    
2               Customer 2    Address 2    Billing
3               Customer 3    Address 3    Billing
```

The second table includes customer shipping information, and has another customer number. The "Partner" column references the billing information:

```
ShippingTable

Customer     Name         Address        Type      Partner(PK)
--------- -----------  --------------  ---------- ------------
4          Customer 1    Sh.Address 1   Shipping      1
5          Customer 2    Sh.Address 2   Shipping      2
6          Customer 4    Sh.Address 4   Shipping      6
```

As you can see, there are entries in the billing information table that are not referenced in the shipping information table. It also happens, that a customer has shipping information but no billing information. In this case, the partner column contains the customer number from the shipping information table.

I have to merge both tables into the following:

```
ResultTable

Customer(PK)     Shipping      Name         Address        Type
-------------  -----------  ------------  ------------  ----------
1                   4        Customer 1    Address 1      Billing
2                   5        Customer 2    Address 2      Billing
3                            Customer 3    Address 3      Billing
6                   6        Customer 4    Sh.Address 4   Shipping
```

So I need a table in which just the shipping customer number is added to the billing table, if there is one. If not, the shipping column can remain blank. If there is shipping information but no billing information, I would like to get the entire row from the ShippingTable.

When simply using the `DataTable.Merge()` method like `BillingTable.Merge(ShippingTable)`, the address and type columns of the billing table are overwritten by the shipping information. When setting preserveChanges to true like `BillingTable.Merge(ShippingTable, true)`, it doesn't merge the shipping customer numbers into the BillingTable, but just adds the additional shipping customer information to the table.

I also tried to "manually" get the shipping number for each row, by looping thorugh them and using Linq to get the required shipping information. But as I am working with a huge amount of rows, this takes really, really long.

The next thing I tried was to delete the Address and Type column from the ShippingTable before merging. But in this case of course, I loose the information of customers who do not have billing information.

So to wrap it up, this is what I've tried so far:

```cs
BillingTable.Merge(ShippingTable); // Billing info is overwritten

BillingTable.Merge(ShippingTable, true); // Does not merge shipping number

// Loop through each row, takes very long 
foreach(DataRow row in BillingTable.Rows) {

    row["Shipping"] = ShippingTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                                   .Where(shRow => shRow["Partner"].ToString() == row["Customer"])
                                   .First()
                                   .Field<string>("Customer");
}

// Delete Address and Type columns before merging
// Does not include address and type information for shipping only entries
ShippingTable.Columns.Remove("Address");
ShippingTable.Columns.Remove("Type");

BillingTable.Merge(ShippingTable);
```

And here the results:

With BillingTable.Merge(ShippingTable)

```
Customer(PK)     Shipping      Name         Address        Type
-------------  -----------  ------------  -------------  ---------
1                   4        Customer 1    Sh.Address 1   Shipping
2                   5        Customer 2    Sh.Address 2   Shipping
3                            Customer 3     Address 3     Billing
6                   6        Customer 4    Sh.Address 4   Shipping
```

With BillingTable.Merge(ShippingTable, true)

```
Customer(PK)     Shipping      Name         Address        Type
-------------  ------------ ------------  -------------  ---------
1                            Customer 1    Address 1      Billing
2                            Customer 2    Address 2      Billing
3                            Customer 3     Address 3     Billing
6                   6        Customer 4    Sh.Address 4   Shipping
```

When deleting "Address" and "Type" Column from ShippingTable before merging:

```
Customer(PK)     Shipping      Name         Address        Type
-------------  -----------  ------------  ------------  ----------
1                   4        Customer 1    Address 1      Billing
2                   5        Customer 2    Address 2      Billing
3                            Customer 3    Address 3      Billing
6                   6
```

So either there is a way of merging the tables that I wasn't able to find so far or I will have to do it another way. I thought about joining the tables whith SQL when getting them from the the Excel files or to join the tables with Linq instead of `DataTable.Merge()`, but I couldn't get either way to work properly.

Can someone help, please?

(sorry for the long description)

Answer (score 0):

So well, it seems the solution was to easy for me to think of.

I simply switched the tables and did `DataTable.Merge()` the other way round. So the solution to this would be:

```cs
ShippingTable.Merge(BillingTable);
```